# Get not working for Express using Mongoos

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm new to to writing APIs with Express and Mongoos, but something that I think should work, is causing me some grief.

I'm trying to make things as modular as I can, so I have my main app.js, a model.js and then my routes.js

Here is my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cors = require('cors');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/guestbook');

var app = express();

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors());    

app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));


    // changes it to use the optimized version for production
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));

    // production error handler
    // no stacktraces leaked to user
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: {}
        });
    });


module.exports = app;
```

Here is what I have in my /api (routes file)

```
//DEPENDENCIES
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


//GUESTBOOK END POINTS
var Guestbook = require('../models/guestbook')

router.route('/guestbook')

  .post(function(req, res){

  var guestbook = new Guestbook();

    guestbook.firstname = req.body.firstname;
    guestbook.lastname = req.body.lastname;
    guestbook.email = req.body.email;
    guestbook.postedon = req.body.postedon;
    guestbook.comment = req.body.comment;
    guestbook.rate = req.body.rate;

    guestbook.save(function(err){
      if(err)
        res.send(err);

        res.json({message:'Post created!'})

    });

  })

  .get(function(req, res){
    guestbook.find(function(err, guestbook){
      if(err)
        res.send(err);

        res.json(guestbook);
    });

  });





//RETURN ROUTER AS MODULE
module.exports = router;
```

Finally, here is my model:

```
//DEPENDENCIES
var restful = require('node-restful');
var mongoose = restful.mongoose;

var guestbookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  email: String,
  postedon: Date,
  comment: String,
  rate: Number
});



//RETURN MODEL


module.exports = mongoose.model('guestbook', guestbookSchema);
```

Again, the post works, but the get doesn't.

Here is the console.log I get back for the get:

```
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
   at new View (/Users/christophernakea/Documents/Projects/TestAPIExpress/server/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:62:11)
   at EventEmitter.render (/Users/christophernakea/Documents/Projects/TestAPIExpress/server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:569:12)
   at ServerResponse.render (/Users/christophernakea/Documents/Projects/TestAPIExpress/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:961:7)
   at /Users/christophernakea/Documents/Projects/TestAPIExpress/server/app.js:32:13
   at Layer.handle_error (/Users/christophernakea/Documents/Projects/TestAPIExpress/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
   at trim_prefix (/Users/christophernakea/Documents/Projects/TestAPIExpress/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:310:13)
   at /Users/christophernakea/Documents/Projects/TestAPIExpress/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
   at Function.process_params (/Users/christophernakea/Documents/Projects/TestAPIExpress/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
   at next (/Users/christophernakea/Documents/Projects/TestAPIExpress/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
   at Layer.handle_error (/Users/christophernakea/Documents/Projects/TestAPIExpress/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:67:12)
   at trim_prefix (/Users/christophernakea/Documents/Projects/TestAPIExpress/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:310:13)
   at /Users/christophernakea/Documents/Projects/TestAPIExpress/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
   at Function.process_params (/Users/christophernakea/Documents/Projects/TestAPIExpress/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
   at Immediate.next (/Users/christophernakea/Documents/Projects/TestAPIExpress/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
   at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Users/christophernakea/Documents/Projects/TestAPIExpress/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:618:15)
   at Immediate.immediate._onImmediate (timers.js:435:18)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the probleme was that your are trying to render a page without specifying the template engine, since you are creating just an API, you don't need to render any page, so you need to just return a json 
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: {}

you can replace it by res.json('error': err.message)

Comment: I tried replacing the line:  if(err)  res.send(err); with  res.json('error': err.message) and get the same error...

Comment: @cnak2 res.send() do not render a template. So replacing that line will not have any effect.

Comment: @hatim, so where are you suggesting I replace the code generates the following error:  res.json('error': err.message);
                 ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you have not set a template engine with the express framework. Refer to the [express guide](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) related to this topic.

This line

```
res.render('error', {
   message: err.message,
   error: {}
});
```

Renders a template. But you don't have configure which one to use.

Comment: I don't see that line in my code. I'm actually returning:  res.send(err); Not 'render'.

Comment: you are using render at app.js

Comment: Oh, I see. And because there is an error on my route, it's trying to send the error message and render it in the app.js...

Comment: I don't want to render any pages. Just want to send back data results form the api to angular. I changed the code in app.js to the following and still get the same error, so I'm still missing something:     app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.json('error': err.message);
    });

Comment: exactly @cnak2. thats the case

Comment: Check in the error message the location of your use of render. In the case of the error message you are presenting is the 5th line